# Custom registration form don't register the user and no error message is shown

Tags: django, django-forms, django-views, django-users

I've create a registration form divided in two part: company's datas and rapresentative's datas.

At the start of developing I'm interesting only at the company's datas and, as tests, I've registered the users both use the default Django admin panel that my form.

Now I've upgraded the model for registration with other datas.
When I send the datas the new user is registered only if I use  the default Django admin panel, but if I use my form something was wrong because I see on the terminal the message `Invalid form. Something was wrong!!`

I don't understand where is the error because on the terminal there isn't another error message even if I delete `print("Invalid form. Something was wrong!!")`.

**form.py**

```
class UserProfileCreationForm(UserCreationForm):
    username = forms.CharField(
        widget=forms.TextInput(attrs={
                'placeholder': 'Write the username',
                'class': 'form-control',
                }
            ),
        label='Company Username',
        help_text='Write the name of your Company',
        required=False,
        )
    password1 = forms.CharField(
        label="Password",
        widget=forms.PasswordInput(attrs={
                'class': 'form-control',
                }
            ),
        strip=False,
        help_text=password_validation.password_validators_help_text_html(),
        )
    password2 = forms.CharField(
        label="Password confirmation",
        widget=forms.PasswordInput(attrs={
                'class': 'form-control',
                }
            ),
        )
    company_name = forms.CharField(
        widget=forms.TextInput(attrs={
                'placeholder': 'Write the name of your Company',
                'class': 'form-control',
                }
            ),
        label='Name of Company',
        )
    company_city = forms.CharField(
        widget=forms.TextInput(attrs={
                'placeholder': 'Write the name of the city in which there is the registered office of your Company',
                'class': 'form-control',
                }
            ),
        label='City',
        )
    company_address = forms.CharField(
        widget=forms.TextInput(attrs={
                'placeholder': 'Write the address of the registered office',
                'class': 'form-control',
                }
            ),
        label='Address',
        )
    company_postcode = forms.CharField(
        widget=forms.TextInput(attrs={
                'placeholder': 'Write the zip code of the registered office',
                'class': 'form-control',
                }
            ),
        label='Zip Code',
        )
    company_country = forms.CharField(
        widget=forms.TextInput(attrs={
                'placeholder': 'Write the Country in which there is the registered office',
                'class': 'form-control',
                }
            ),
        label='Country',
        )
    company_region = forms.CharField(
        widget=forms.TextInput(attrs={
                'placeholder': 'Write the Region in which there is the registered office',
                'class': 'form-control',
                }
            ),
        label='Region',
        )
    company_telephone_number = forms.CharField(
        widget=forms.TextInput(attrs={
                'placeholder': 'Write the telephone of the registered office',
                'class': 'form-control',
                }
            ),
        label='Main Company telephone number',
        )
    company_email = forms.EmailField(
        widget=forms.EmailInput(attrs={
                'placeholder': 'Write the email of the registered office',
                'class': 'form-control',
                }
            ),
        label='Main Company email',
        )
    representative_name = forms.CharField(
        widget=forms.TextInput(attrs={
                'placeholder': 'Write the name of the person that represent the Company on this platform',
                'class': 'form-control',
                }
            ),
        label='Representative name',
        )
    representative_surname = forms.CharField(
        widget=forms.TextInput(attrs={
                'placeholder': 'Write the surname of the person that represent the Company on this platform',
                'class': 'form-control',
                }
            ),
        label='Representative surname',
        )
    representative_role = forms.CharField(
        widget=forms.TextInput(attrs={
                'placeholder': 'Write the role of the person that represent the Company on this platform',
                'class': 'form-control',
                }
            ),
        label='Role',
        )
    representative_telephone = forms.CharField(
        widget=forms.TextInput(attrs={
                'placeholder': 'Write the telephone of the person that represent the Company on our platform',
                'class': 'form-control',
                }
            ),
        label='Representative telephone number',
        )
    representative_email = forms.EmailField(
        widget=forms.EmailInput(attrs={
                'placeholder': 'Write the email of the person that represent the Company on our platform',
                'class': 'form-control',
                }
            ),
        label='Representative email',
        )

    class Meta:
        model = User
        fields = [
            'username', 'password1', 'password2',
            'company_name', 'company_address', 'company_city', 'company_postcode', 'company_region', 'company_country', 'company_telephone_number', 'company_email',
            'representative_name', 'representative_surname', 'representative_role', 'representative_telephone', 'representative_email',
            ]

    def clean(self):
        super().clean()
        password1 = self.cleaned_data["password1"]
        password2 = self.cleaned_data["password2"]
        if password1 != password2:
            raise forms.ValidationError(
                self.error_messages['password_mismatch'],
                code='password_mismatch',
            )
        return self.cleaned_data
```

**view.py**

```
def createUser(request):
    if request.method == "POST":
        form = UserProfileCreationForm(request.POST)
        if form.is_valid():
            username = form.cleaned_data["username"]
            password = form.cleaned_data["password1"]
            company_name = form.cleaned_data["company_name"]
            company_city = form.cleaned_data["company_city"]
            company_address = form.cleaned_data["company_address"]
            company_postcode = form.cleaned_data["company_postcode"]
            company_country = form.cleaned_data["company_country"]
            company_region = form.cleaned_data["company_region"]
            company_telephone_number = form.cleaned_data["company_telephone_number"]
            company_email = form.cleaned_data["company_email"]
            representative_name = form.cleaned_data["representative_name"]
            representative_surname = form.cleaned_data["representative_surname"]
            representative_role = form.cleaned_data["representative_role"]
            representative_telephone = form.cleaned_data["representative_telephone"]
            representative_email = form.cleaned_data["representative_email"]
            UserProfile.objects.create_user(
                username=username, password=password,
                company_name=company_name, company_city=company_city, company_address=company_address,
                company_postcode=company_postcode, company_country=company_country, company_region=company_region,
                company_telephone_number=company_telephone_number, company_email=company_email,
                representative_name=representative_name, representative_surname=representative_surname, representative_role=representative_role,
                representative_telephone=representative_telephone, representative_email=representative_email,
                )
            print("I'm sending you at the profile!")
            return HttpResponseRedirect("/hub/user/")
        else:
            print("Invalid form. Something was wrong!!")
            return HttpResponseRedirect("/")
    else:
        form = UserProfileCreationForm()

    template = 'usermanager/editing/create_user.html'
    context = {'form': form}
    return render(request, template, context)
```

**templates.html**

```
  <form class="" action="" method="POST" novalidate>
    {% csrf_token %}
    {#{ form.errors }#}
    {#{ form.as_p }#}

    {% for field in form %}
      <div class="form-group">

        <div class="row">
          <div class="col-sm-3">
            <strong>{{ field.label_tag }}</strong>
          </div>
          <div class="col-sm-9">
            {{ field }}
            {% if field.errors == True %}
            <div class="alert alert-danger" role="alert">
              {{ field.errors }}
            </div>
            {% endif %}
          </div>
        </div>

      </div>
    {% endfor %}
    <input type="submit" class="btn btn-danger" value="Register">
  </form>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure what you expect. If you get an error, you just print that message and redirect. You are not doing anything to let the user know what actually went wrong.

Django forms contain their own functionality to show validation failures. You should delete that first `else` block entirely, letting flow fall through to the last three lines of the view which will re-render the template with the invalid form. In that template, make sure you are showing `{{ form.errors }}` or the individual errors attributes for each field.

Comment: Thanks @Daniel Roseman For some reason until the representative's datas doesn't appear I can remain blank all the fields of the form(not username and password of course). The if condition of the form template(now I've add it) doesn't work and this is another trick.

Comment: Into models.py all form fields are on `blank=True` then I don't understand why they are required into the form...

Comment: The only one with required=False in that form above is `username` (which seems odd, surely that's the one that is actually required.) But also note that `errors` will never be *equal* to true, it's just truthy in a boolean sense. You should do just `{% if field.errors %}`.

Comment: Thanks, I got confused